# Loop through a collection of bezierCircle [Python]

Tags: python, bezier-curves, constraints, loop

I have this code:

```
import bpy
import numpy
import math 
import os

from mathutils import Euler
from bpy import context, data, ops
from math import radians

#Shortcut for the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene

#Select everything
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
#Remove everything in the scen
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global = True, confirm = False)

#***********************Circles************************
#Definition of constant parameters
Circle_radius   = 1
number_circle   = Circle_radius*4
Circle_location = (0, 0, 0)

#Defnition of the rotation for the first circle
Circle_rotation = (radians(0), radians(90), radians(0)) 

#Creation of 
for i in range(number_circle):
    #Definition of the geometry of the circle
    Curve = bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add(radius   = Circle_radius,
                                                      location = Circle_location,
                                                      rotation = Circle_rotation)    
    #Defnition of the rotation for the other circle
    temp = Circle_rotation[0]
    temp = temp + radians(45)
    
    #Create a collection with only circle components
    Circle_rotation = (temp, radians(90), radians(0)) 
    
#***********************Camera parameters************************
focal    = 3.04  #focal lenght (mm)
sw       = 3.68  #sensor width (mm)
sh       = 2.76  #sensor height (mm)
eul_mode = 'XYZ'

#Define the number of camera we want
#number_cam = number_circle + 1
number_cam = number_circle 

#Add camera in the scene with the location and rotation wanted
for count in range(number_cam):
    #Creation of the camera as a camera
   cam_name = f'Camera{count}'
   cam      = bpy.data.cameras.new(name = cam_name)
   cam.sensor_fit = 'HORIZONTAL' 
   cam.lens       = focal
   cam.sensor_width  = sw
   cam.sensor_height = sh
   
    #Creation of the camera as an object
   cam_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(cam_name, cam)
   cam_obj.rotation_mode  = eul_mode
   cam_obj.location       = (0, 0, 0)
   cam_obj.rotation_euler = (radians(0), radians(0), radians(0))
   scene.collection.objects.link(cam_obj)
   
   cam_obj.scale = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
   
    #*****************Clamping **************************
for cam in [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.type == 'CAMERA']:
    #Definition of the tracking parameters (target and who is tracking)
    target = bpy.data.objects['BezierCircle']
    Camera = cam

    #Add a constraint
    tracking = Camera.constraints.new(type ='CLAMP_TO')

    #Add a target
    tracking.target = target

    #Definition of the axis
    tracking.main_axis  = 'CLAMPTO_Z'
    tracking.use_cyclic = True

    #Select the object on which the constraint is applyed
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action ='DESELECT')
    Camera.select_set(True)

    #Apply the constraint
    bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()

    #Influence = 0
    Camera.constraints.get("Clamp To").influence = 1
```

And I would like to loop through a collection of bezierCircle to change the target of the constraint.

Do you know how I can do that? Thanks for your help